# How to display all TODO items from a single file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am still new to org-mode and emacs, so please forgive me for asking such a simple question.

I organise my `org-mode` files one per area of interest: so I have one for work, one for personal projects, etc. These files contain both notes and `TODO` entries, so it's really hard to see all the `TODO` items in the given file...

**So here is my question:**

Is there an easy way to easy *filter all the todo items in agenda view by file they are in*?

The only way I can think of right now is by using a special tag per file, but this will require me to update all files and all entries it's quite a lot of work I would prefer to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Basic TODO functionality](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-basics.html#TODO-basics) section in the manual: `C-c / t` constructs a "sparse tree" of all TODO items in a single file; `C-c a t` constructs a global TODO list out of all files that have been added to the agenda.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a per-file tag in a "FILETAGS" header for the file, so although you'd need to edit each file it's only one line per file.  I use three, "@work" "@home" "@personal".  Can then filter on tags in agenda views.

`#+FILETAGS: @work`

Comment: Thanks also a nice idea, thanks :) But the answer above is exactly what I needed.